# How do I change the control used by TreeViewItem in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

When I declare a `TreeView` in the `XAML`, I can use a control of my choice (here, a `StackPanel`) for the elements that are immediately added to it:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DockPanel Name="dockPanel1">
        <TreeView Name="treeView1">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <ProgressBar Height="15" Width="160" />
                        <TextBlock Foreground="Red" Text="{Binding}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <sys:String>Foo</sys:String>
            <sys:String>Bar</sys:String>
        </TreeView>
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

How can I achieve the same thing when adding elements from the C# code?

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            // I want something more complex than just "Quux".
            var item = new TreeViewItem { Header = "Quux" };
            treeView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> When I declare a TreeView in the XAML, I can use a control of my choice (here, a StackPanel) for the elements that are immediately added to it

That goes for *all* items, in code just do:

```
treeView1.Items.Add("Text");
```

Or

```
treeView1.ItemsSource = new[]
{
    "One", "Two"
};
```

Unless you add UI elements the defined `DataTemplate` will be used.

Might want to read [some references](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx)...

Comment: Oh, I did'nt know you could do that. But then, how do you get a reference to the `item` you just added (to modify it later or add subitems)? Currently I do `var myItem = new TreeViewItem { Header = "Quux" }; treeView1.Items.Add(item); item.Items.Add("SubItem"); item.Header="Change the text";`, but if instead I did `int index = treeView1.Items.Add("Quux");` then it's more difficult to add a subitem to `Quux` nor change its text.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: Just store a reference *before* adding it, and don't even think about using indices. Also if you add strings directly you cannot modify them, use classes with properties and bind those. **Read the reference**.

Comment: What I meant was "How do I get a reference to the item just added?" If I keep a reference to `"Text"`, then it will be a reference to the string `"Text"`, not a reference to the `TreeViewItem` that is magically created by `.Items.Add()`. I want to get a reference to the "thing" that was created by `.Items.Add("Text")`, but that method's return type is `int`, not `TreeViewItem`.

Comment: @GeorgesDupéron: Rethink your design, you usually should not need a reference to the `TreeViewItem`. If you need to modify some aspect of the item, then create respective properties and bind them in the `ItemContainerStyle`.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it :) .

```
namespace WpfApplication5
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();

            var stackPanel = new StackPanel { Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal };
            stackPanel.Children.Add(new ProgressBar { Height = 15, Width = 160 });
            stackPanel.Children.Add(new TextBlock { Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red), Text = "Quux" });

            var item = new TreeViewItem { Header = stackPanel };
            treeView1.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do this in XAML. Manipulating UI elements in procedural code is not needed nor desired in WPF.

Comment: @HighCore I doubt writing a for loop with calls to other methods adding hundreds of elements in XAML would look pretty, if at all possible... Unless you mean one should use data binding ?

Comment: there's no "for" loop in WPF. There is `ItemsControl`s, `DataTemplate`s, and `DataBinding`.